# Should I be concerned about the performance problems of Object.setPrototypeOf when subclassing Error?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have questions about the `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype)` function because of this [MDN warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

> **Warning:** Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine. In addition, the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to the time spent in the `Object.setPrototypeOf(...)` statement, but may extend to ***any*** code that has access to any object whose `[[Prototype]]` has been altered. You can read more in [JavaScript engine fundamentals: optimizing prototypes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes).
>
> Because this feature is a part of the language, it is still the burden on engine developers to implement that feature performantly (ideally). Until engine developers address this issue, if you are concerned about performance, you should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

So what would be the best way to restore the prototype string in TypeScript (Node.js) without using `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype)` (but using classes)? This is all because of an error management middleware implemented in Express, in which I need to make use of `instanceof` to determine the origin of the error and thus return a proper response, but whenever I make a class that extends from Error, the `error instanceof Error` returns true, but `error instanceof CustomError` returns false. Doing a little research I found this in [the official TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-newtarget):

> ### Support for `new.target`
>
> The `new.target` meta-property is new syntax introduced in ES2015. When an instance of a constructor is created via `new`, the value of `new.target` is set to be a reference to the constructor function initially used to allocate the instance. If a function is called rather than constructed via `new`, `new.target` is set to `undefined`.
>
> `new.target` comes in handy when `Object.setPrototypeOf` or `__proto__` needs to be set in a class constructor. One such use case is inheriting from `Error` in NodeJS v4 and higher.
>
> ###### Example
>
> ```ts
> class CustomError extends Error {
>   constructor(message?: string) {
>     super(message); // 'Error' breaks prototype chain here
>     Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype); // restore prototype chain
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This results in the generated JS
>
> ```js
> var CustomError = (function(_super) {
>   __extends(CustomError, _super);
>   function CustomError() {
>     var _newTarget = this.constructor;
>     var _this = _super.apply(this, arguments); // 'Error' breaks prototype chain here
>     _this.__proto__ = _newTarget.prototype; // restore prototype chain
>     return _this;
>   }
>   return CustomError;
> })(Error);
> ```

And I thought okay everything is perfect since the code at the moment of being converted, I suppose that the compiler will take care of that function that is slow and will replace it with another procedure that is more efficient, but to my surprise it's not like that and I'm a little worried about the performance (I'm working on a big project).

I'm using TypeScript version 3.9.6 in Node 14.5.0, these are screenshots of the tests I did:

- [TypeScript with Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoXlN.png)
- [TypeScript Playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jysGE.png)
- [TypeScript compiler results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxSZE.png)

Comment: I wonder if it's been changed since ES2015. I can't see anything in the release notes that mention this.

Comment: "_So what would be the best way to restore the prototype string in TypeScript_" what is a "prototype string"?

Comment: I see that the main reason you want to replace the prototype is because of the `instanceof` checks. [Link to an issue from a few years ago](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965). But now, if your TSConfig targets ES2015 and later, you don't need to replace the prototype, as it will return `true` just like in the playground.

Comment: `"Remember that this is only an issue if your compilation target is ES3 or ES5. Instead of having to remember to set the prototype, you could consider upgrading your target to ES 2015 or even later."` (quoted from https://dannyguo.medium.com/how-to-fix-instanceof-not-working-for-custom-errors-in-typescript-1df978100a27 )
And in your case, it's not even a browser; it's Node 14, which supports ES6 `class`es.

Comment: Also related: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#inheriting-built-in-types

Comment: @user3840170 frankly, I like the new title you've given this question, but I'm concerned about the fact that you've changed the title to ask a fundamentally different question. Now, I like the new question you've changed it to. I think it might be a better fit for the Stack Exchange model, but it makes me uneasy. I'm interested in what the original asker and bounty placer think of this. (Thanks for your other edits though) Also notice that the body of the post still contains the original question. Now the title and body questions are out of sync :/ That's pretty confusing for answerers too.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn’t worry about it.

- First of all, as a general rule, you should not expect your program will spend most of its running time creating error objects: instead, it will be serving requests successfully.  You should not be micro-optimising code that is only going to run rarely: unless you perform exhaustive tests, any such micro-optimisation risks introducing bugs that will be only discovered much, much later.
- The warning is only meant to discourage you from *frivolously* changing the object’s prototype.  Which is to say, doing so in a way that is *avoidable* (by redesigning your data structures), and after the object has already been handed to other places that will use it intensely.  This is because changing prototypes disturbs the invariants on which property lookup caches rely, as described in [the article linked in that warning box](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes).  The author of the latter even writes this in the article’s summary (emphasis mine):

  > Leave your prototypes alone! Or **if you really need to touch prototypes, then do it before other code runs**, so that you at least don’t invalidate all the optimizations in the engine while your code is running.

  In the case of subclassing `Error`, you really need to change the object’s prototype one way or another (with `Object.setPrototypeOf` or its predecessor `__proto__`) for the sake of correctness, and it cannot be avoided, for otherwise `instanceof` would not work as intended (as noted in the question).  And since you do it in the constructor, near the beginning of the object’s lifetime, it is also relatively benign in terms of performance, as the aforementioned property lookup caches will presumably not have been generated yet at that point.

  Contrast this use with the following reimplementation of `Object.hasOwn`:

  ```js
  function hasOwn(obj, key) {
      var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
      Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, null);
      try {
          return key in obj;
      } finally {
          Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, proto);
      }
  }
  ```

  Using that instead of the real `Object.hasOwn` (or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`) would have been a terrible idea that would basically destroy the performance of your program.
- Last but not least: the problems with `Error` subclasses not having the correct prototype only appear when subclassing is emulated using ECMAScript 5 features, i.e. by calling `Error.apply`.  When using native ECMAScript 6 subclassing, the issue goes away (per later, [it would also go away if TypeScript used `Reflect.construct`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76135991/3840170) instead of `Function.prototype.apply`, but [so far it has not been doing so](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15397)).  Since you target Node 14, you can simply configure TypeScript to emit ECMAScript 6 code and forget about it.  You can even leave the `Object.setPrototypeOf` call in place, in case you ever need that class in code that will also be transpiled into ECMAScript 5; in the circumstance where the prototype is set correctly from the start, the call will be turned into a no-op, making any performance impact negligible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this "In the case of subclassing Error, you really need to use Object.setPrototypeOf for correctness, and it cannot be avoided". Why do we really need this