# Why does Babel use Reflect.construct when transpiling ES6 classes into ES5?

Tags: inheritance, ecmascript-6, constructor, babeljs

For the sake of old browser support, we all use BabelJS to transpile ES6 into ES5. When Babel compiles a class that extends another class, there is a part of compiled code that looks like this:

```js
function _createSuper(Derived) {
  var hasNativeReflectConstruct = _isNativeReflectConstruct();
  return function _createSuperInternal() {
    var Super = _getPrototypeOf(Derived),
      result;
    if (hasNativeReflectConstruct) {
      var NewTarget = _getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
      result = Reflect.construct(Super, arguments, NewTarget);
    } else {
      result = Super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, result);
  };
}
```

I know the `_createSuper` function is meant to create a function wrapping the process of calling the superclass, which binds `this` as subclass's receiver, so that the subclass can inherit its superclass's properties. To fulfil this purpose, what we need to do is only let `result = Super.apply(this, arguments)`. But the code checks if the environment supports `Reflect` and uses `Reflect.construct` preferentially. I actually don't know why we need `result = Reflect.construct(Super, arguments, NewTarget)` and what it does. Can someone explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of object construction (as performed by `Reflect.construct`) and of `Function.prototype.apply` are not identical.  They were very similar (at least for user-code functions) before ECMAScript 6, but there are some noticeable differences, and those have only accumulated over time.  Opportunistically using `Reflect.construct` allows applying true construction semantics when possible, instead of the merely approximative function-call semantics.

For a simple case: native ECMAScript 6 classes cannot be invoked like functions at all (directly, via `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`); they can only be invoked as constructors, using the `new` operator or `Reflect.construct`.  When the base class of a transpiled class happens to be a native ECMAScript 6 class, using `Reflect.construct` allows subclassing to happen (mostly) transparently.

```js
// non-transpiled class

class Clbutt {
  constructor(x, y) {
    console.log(`Clbutt constructin’ a ${new.target?.name}`);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  toString() {
    return `{ ${Object.entries(this)
      .map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`)
      .join(", ")} }`;
  }
}

// (simplified) transpiled class

function Subclbutt(x, y) {
  // this would have been a TypeError:
  // var ðis = Clbutt.apply(this, arguments);

  var ðis = Reflect.construct(Clbutt, arguments, this.constructor);
  console.log("Subclbutt constructin’");
  ðis.dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  return ðis;
}

// probably polyfilled using the non-standard __proto__ if absent
Object.setPrototypeOf(Subclbutt.prototype, Clbutt.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Subclbutt, Clbutt);

// user code

console.log(`${new Clbutt(3, 4)}`);
console.log(`${new Subclbutt(3, 4)}`);
```

A similar issue appears when subclassing certain built-in classes like `Map` and `Promise`, or DOM classes like `Element`; those constructors also cannot be invoked as functions.  Not that subclassing built-ins is a great idea in the first place, but if directly-run code can do it, then transpiled code should probably also be able to.

In fact, in ECMAScript 6 even plain functions can distinguish between being invoked normally and being invoked as constructors, by checking whether `new.target` is an object or undefined.  Using `Reflect.construct` instead of `Function.prototype.apply` eliminates this divergence as well.